# obtain and grab single value from getCookie() function

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I am trying to use the `getCookie()` function and grab the `sessionID`'s **value**.

When I call the following function in my code:

```
let sessionCookie = await this.driver.manage().getCookie(['sessionid']);
console.log(sessionCookie)
```

I get this response:

```
 {
  domain: 'xxx.xxxxxx.xxx',
  expiry: 1629398293,
  httpOnly: true,
  name: 'sessionid',
  path: '/',
  secure: true,
  value: 'bte8erv3t3piimsu3cmoqv3wvp16i2jj'
}
```

How do I get the string of characters from `value` ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi just add 'value' for console.log

```
let sessionCookie = await this.driver.manage().getCookie(['sessionid']);
console.log(sessionCookie.value)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. to make this a global method to return the value, would something such as this work?
---


   `getSessionCookie: async () => {
      let sessionCookie = this.driver.manage().getCookie('sessionid');
      return sessionCookie.value
    }`
---

Comment: if u wanna use it like global u should pass some params into this function, will be more flexible, because right now u get only sessionId..
getMyCookie(name) { ... manage().getCookie(name) .. } 
And 1 more thing if u don't wanna use 'await', don't need use 'async'